# Teamcity interaction with powershell script

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a powershell script that runs for ~30 minutes (waiting on various process' to finish). At the end, it writes a message to the event log, determining if the process was a success or failure. I plan on hosting this script on teamcity and want the build to fail, but don't know how to handle the interaction between the script and teamcity in order for this to happen.

I'm looking for a way to make a powershell script that is ran remotely to communicate to teamcity whether it was a failure or success. I've read up on a lot of the teamcity documentation and I'm still not sure how to start going about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably consider using TeamCity [Service Messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-servMsgsServiceMessages), or specifically [Reporting Build Problems](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildProblems).

An example of how to emit a service message using PowerShell (assuming you're using the PowerShell build step):

```
Write-Output "##teamcity[buildStatus text='I am a successful build']"
```

or

```
Write-Output "##teamcity[buildProblem description='$powershell_error_message']"
```

where you can inject the captured powershell error message.

Comment: One thing to note for others that see this is that I had to add a specific fail condition under build configurations>failure conditions that matched the description in order to get it to fail.

Comment: @Speerian That's interesting; I've got a build running with no failure condition and it's failing as expected with a 'buildProblem' service message; using a Powershell runner build step and an inline source script.  Perhaps there's different behaviour when executing external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To intentionally fail a build in teamcity you should use "[Environment] :: Exit (1)" instead of "Exit 1".

More information can be obtained at the link below:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/PowerShell